# Query to see if row exists based on data without selecting fields

Tags: mysql

So i know how to check a row exists from a set of data. But a lot of examples i find entails selecting a row and bunch of fields - something i don't need in this case.

In my case i just need to know it exists. I was wondering if there is a way to check a row exists without `selecting/getting` the row since thats some what redundant data ?

If not i will stick to using my `SELECT id` approach but wanted to see if i had missed a better approach just to ping the existence of a row.

Currently i am doing:

```
SELECT uid FROM users WHERE sessionID = ? AND uid = ?
```

Then i am checking if row count is == 1 afterwards. But i am still needlessly getting `uid` which i already technically have. It seems inefficient. So perhaps there is a better way built into mySQL?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What about adding COUNT to your select statement and checking if it != 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
select (exists (select 1 from t) ) as exists_flag
```

This returns 1 if the row exists or 0 if no row exists.  You can add a `where` clause to the subquery if you want a particular row.

Comment: Oh you can make your own field name ! I always thought it had to be one from the table i was selecting from! Neat ! Thank you.